# How do I connect my Raspberry Pi to my Linux Laptop?

Tags: raspberry-pi, linux-mint

I want to be able to connect my Raspberry Pi to my laptop (it runs Linux Mint). I have tried to look it up on Youtube, and I Googled it, but it seems like it is too confusing. I have a Raspberry Pi B. I want to be able to view the Raspberry Pi desktop on my laptop screen, and be able to operate it like a normal monitor screen.

Comment: Using Ethernet cable? Or WiFi? Or serial? Or Bluetooth? With a view to sending or receiving what? This doesn't seem to be a programming question so it probably belongs on a different StackExchange site - maybe Superuser?

Comment: "How do I connect A to B" is too broad and too vague to be answerable.  Do you mean connect physically, or more of a logical connection where they can communicate over a network?  For what purpose are you connecting them?

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of ways you can talk to the raspberry pi, although I wouldn't use "connect" as the word.

Here's a few things you can do.  Most require that you do some config on the raspberry pi to enable it first (since it's a security vulnerability to leave everything enabled by default.

1. SSH - Access the command line of the raspberry pi from any device in the network.
   Enable SSH by running "sudo raspi-config" then navigate to "interfaces", "ssh", "enable".  If you are connected to a network (either wireless or wired), from your laptop, you can type "ssh pi@192.168.1.99" (replace the IP address with the IP address of your raspberry pi).
2. Serial - Access the command line of the raspberry pi using a USB to Serial (TTL/UART) cable.
   Enable this by running "sudo raspi-config", navigate to interfaces, serial, enable.  If you have a USB to Serial (TTL) cable, you can wire it up to the GPIO pins on the raspberry pi that are used for UART (serial) communication.
3. If you want to "remote desktop" into it, this gets a little trickier.  You can install a program on the raspberry pi, and potentially your laptop as well.  This guide explains the setup better than I can:  https://www.datenreise.de/en/raspberry-pi-install-remote-desktop-xrdp/